# Virtual Pageview Goal Funnel Not Tracking Correctly

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, goals

I have an AJAX form that has three stages:
1. The landing page where a user fills out a form and selects between three question sets and clicks begin assessment
2. The assessment page, where users fill out questions relating to the question set that they selected on the landing page.
3.The results page, which shows whether they are at High Risk or Low Risk.

Since this is an AJAX form that does not open a new page for each step of the process, I implemented a virtual pageview that would fire on the pageload of each step of the form process.

The following is my virtual pageview setup for each stage:

1. /form/begin-assessment
2. /form/assessment/*      (* = Three different virtual pageviews depending on the users selection of the three sets of questions: /one, /two, /three)
   3./form/finished-assessment

I have set up three separate goals to track user progress through each step of the form assessment. Here is my Goal setup:

Goal Description: 
-Goal Type: Destination

Goal Details:
-Destination: /form/finished-assessment
-Funnel: On
Step 1: /form/begin-assessment (Required: Yes)
Step 2: /form/assessment/one

(Step 2: replace /one with /two or /three and you have my two other goals setup)

Now my goals are recording the correct data in the first step and show the completions in the destination, but the second step does not show any drop offs. They show the same data as the destination.

Any ideas of how I set up the goals wrong?

Answer (score 1):

@cphill if you're using those URL's as virtual page views match the URL's and have them as steps to conversions, rather than multiple goals. If the ultimate goal is the thank you page. Track each step within one goal. Also use developer tool and look at the source to make sure you're firing off the virtual page view correctly after each step in the form

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that /form/assessment/* pages are showing up in the pages report (Site Content > All Pages > (do a search for /form/assessment/)?

Comment: Yes they are appearing

Comment: What match type are you using on the destination URL? If it's regex, try escaping the slashes in the urls for the goal steps. Could you take a screen shot of the funnel and the goal details?